# react-bootstrap edit input fields in a Modal after it's done displaying initial data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

`TL DR` Summary: I have a table that shows a list of members. I click on a row and it renders a Modal with more info for that specific user. Now, I need to be able to edit the input fields within the Modal and save back in the DB.

`Full Scenario:`

I am using `react-bootstrap` to render a `Modal` for displaying additional data about the members that are initially displayed in an `HTML` table rows.

When I click on the row, the `Modal` shows up and renders all additional details into the appropriate `input` fields.

From a parent class (which is just a sibling class just above the `MemberModal`) I am rendering the `Modal` like this. The `selectedMember` state variable contains the user whose additional details needs to be displayed.

```
<MemberModal
      show={this.state.showMemberModal}
      onHide={closeMemberModal}
      selectedmember={this.state.selectedMember}
/>
```

Here is my `MemberModal` class:

```
class MemberModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ member: this.props.selectedmember.firstName });
  }
  handleFirstNameChange = e => {
    this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value });
  };

  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="static-modal">
        // Abstracted some Modal design JSX code .......
                <input
                  value={this.props.selectedmember.firstName}
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="FirstName"
                  aria-describedby="FirstName"
                  placeholder=""
                  name="email"
                  onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}
                />
              </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the additional details show up in the `Modal` very accurately BUT I am not able to edit it. It probably is firing `onChange` every time I type in new characters/delete but the input field still maintains to show the old value it was loaded with.

**Update 1:** [Pastebin Full Code](https://pastebin.com/StF3CXfk)

Comment: On a change, you'll need to update `firstName` in the state of the ancestor component from where the value `this.props.selectedmember.firstName` is coming.

Comment: @Oblosys Could you please look at my pastebin Update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues with your `MemberModal` component:

1. You were setting `this.state.member` instead of `this.state.firstName` in your `componentDidMount`.
2. Removed `componentDidMount` and instead initialized `this.state.firstName` to `props.selectedmember.firstname` in the constructor.
3. You had the input value set to `this.props.selectedmember.firstname`, but that value was never getting updated. Instead, your input should be bound to `this.state.firstName`.

**Changes:**

```
class MemberModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName: props.selectedmember.firstName
        };
    }

    handleFirstNameChange = e => {
        this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value });
        // Make call to API to save changes here
        User.save({ firstName: e.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        const { firstName } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="static-modal">
                <input
                    value={firstName}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="FirstName"
                    aria-describedby="FirstName"
                    placeholder=""
                    name="email"
                    onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This will make it editable on screen, but won't record the changes anywhere.

Comment: @Oblosys Yes OP didn't provide any details on how it should be saved.

Comment: True, if there will be some sort of commit button, this is fine.

Comment: Guys, please look at my pastebin Update 1

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I don't understand the `const { firstName } = this.state;` part. You are setting the whole state obj into a firstName var. With your changes, the modal loads and the First Name field is now empty rather than showing a default name.

Comment: @summerNight I'm not assigning a value, it's called [destructuring an object](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html).

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda: If I am not asking for too much, could you please checkout my pastebin to make sure if your changes would still apply? I tried in your changes and it still does not work (at least for me). I have been kind of stuck at it for 2 weeks now and trying to figure it out every single day.